# Utilizando o comando Update mas não atualiza a coluna na tabela

Tags: sql-update, set

utilizei o seguinte comando :

```
update cliente set telefone = '969843225' where nome = 'João da silva';
```

Depois:

```
select * from cliente;
```

Não atualizou o registro.

Imagem dos registros:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quando você faz o `select * from cliente where nome = 'João da silva' ` retorna o registro correto?

Comment: não apenas nao set as mudanças

Comment: Retificando ele volta  Empty

Comment: Então esse é o problema

Comment: mas como se na figura eu tem o dado telefone 333-5648

Comment: Está faltando a coluna de identificação na sua tabela (ID) ou código do cliente. Quando colocar essa coluna vai poder atualizar por essa coluna e não pelo nome...

Comment: compreedo mas , como é uma aula de demostração o update deveria atuar . engraçado funcional no online da udmy aqui nada rs

Comment: Se o select com o where não funciona com o nome dele o update também não vai funcionar.

Comment: Coloque o ID e atualize pelo ID, veja:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30636e/1

Comment: verdade obrigado . so não consegui entender o motivo .pois no curso ele faz de boa aqui precisa do ID